# How do you manage .vcproj files in source control which are changed by multiple developers?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, merge

We use Subversion as our source control system and store the VisualStudio project files (vcproj) in the source control system as is normal I think. With Subversion we don't use any form of file locking, so if two developers are working on the same project at the same time and both add files to the project, or change settings, the second one to commit has to merge the changes.

How do you merge these changes?

The vcproj files are just text files so it is possible to edit them by hand but they are not very amenable to hand editing, especially by junior developers.

The ways I can think of are

- Get the latest version from svn and re-add all local changes manually
- Edit the file by hand to resolve any conflicts from an automatic merge
- Implement some form of locking scheme to prevent simultaneous changes
- Have an agreement between developers so they do not make simultaneous changes

Currently we are using the first option of re-adding all changes manually but this is time consuming and I was wondering if there is a better way.

With source files the automatic merge feature works most of the time and we don't get  many conflicts.

Comment: You may find that if you're having frequent check-in collisions, you could benefit by changing how your project tree is organized.  IE: instead of having one .vcproj with 500 files in it, have 1 project with 50 files that links to 9 libraries with 50 files each.  If you find you *can't* split your project into separate libraries, it's possible that spending the time to make that possible will in the end increase developer efficiency, because modularity helps with more than just project file maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that option 2 (edit the files by hand) generally works fairly well, as long as you're using a good diff tool (I use [WinMerge](http://www.winmerge.org/)).  The main problem I've run into is that Visual Studio will sometimes reorder the file.  But, if you have a good diff/merge tool then it should be able to differentiate between changed content and moved content.  That can help a lot.

Comment: This is sad.  2010 and VCPROJ files have to be maintained by hand so the revision control system doesn't whack it out.

Comment: Agreed, +1.  95% of the time, the changes are very small (such as adding or deleting 1 or 2 files from the project) and will merge flawlessly.  As long as you're not making grand, sweeping changes to the project file and you look carefully at the merged result before auto-accepting it, you'll be just fine.  In the rare cases where the merge doesn't work, you should remake your local changes.

Answer (score 3):

You might find [Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com/index.php) or [Tools for SLN file](http://slntools.codeplex.com/) useful

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem and I think a weakness in the Visual Studio architecture.  The way we found round it was to not have the proj files in source control at all and to have a build script that handled the configuration settings.

The alternative was very messy and we could not guarantee consistent builds or environments between developers.  This led to a huge number of downstream integration problems and eventually we took the draconian step of removing the project files from source control.

The developers environments could still become misaligned but it showed up when they tried to build things themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Using TFS here, but I don't think it makes a difference.
We also don't lock, and sometimes have to deal with merging project files.  I've never found it to be that complex or much of an issue.  Rarely do we ever experience issues that can't be merged automatically, and the manual merge process is pretty much trivial.

There's only one caveat to this:  Check in often!  If you make major changes to the project structure and don't check them in immediately those changes can start compounding the complexity of later merges.  If I make a major change to the structure of a project, I usually give everybody a heads up.  I'll ask them all to check in their current work, and then take care of the merge myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found this recently: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/vcproj_formatter.aspx
If you run this tool on a vcproj file and on a modified version of it then you can merge them together easily with your favorite text merge tool, and in addition the result is a more compact pretty vcproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Options 1 and 2 are not mutually exclusive - if the developer is junior level, let them use option 1 (re-get the project file and re-do the changes) if that's more comfortable for them.  For more senior developers, option 2 (merge using a merge tool) is perfectly fine.

I think this is a situation that currently has no magic bullet - sometimes merging is a pain.

Answer (score -1):

We use a diff tool ([WinMerge](http://www.winmerge.org/)) to merge changes. The project files are (for the most part) really straight-forward XML. The key here, though, is that there never should be any surprises when merging, because good communication is part of the bed-rock of effective source control.

Simultaneous changes *to the project* are perfectly fine as long as people communicate.

Comment: Heh.  My brain did a small substitution on your last sentence there.  "Simultaneous changes are perfectly fine...as long as I check in first". :)

Comment: if you get above 10 developers or work across several locations or tie zones this is simply not reliable enough to bet your development on.

Comment: I disagree completely. If you're having problems *then you are doing something* wrong. This is precisely what source control should solve!